# access Woo commerce | WordPress methods externally

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to access all WordPress and Woo commerce methods in an external file via load WordPress.

I want to update post meta, update woo-commerce order status and send order complete email to the customer.

Is there any method available?

I tried with below code in `customUpdate.php`

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;
update_post_meta('32387', '_custom_shipping_tracking_no', 'B6hy1q');
$to = 'test@example.com';
$subject = 'Order - 32387 - Updated';
$body = 'Custom Shipping tracking info added for Order - 32387';
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );
```

Comment: this is way too broad. The answer is "yes" but with the amount of detail you gave you probably not going to get much better answers

Comment: please write full questions with all the relevant details, there is no reason people need to ask you to supply them :( Think as if you are talking with strange people that can not read your mind, for example - so that is your code, what is wrong with it?